# Is it possible to send video url to instagram application using intent in android?

Tags: android, instagram

I am using below code for sending video url to instagram app but no luck

String type = "video/*";

String mediaPath= "www.example.com/abcd.mp4";

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        // Set the MIME type
        share.setType(type);

        // Create the URI from the media
        File media = new File(mediaPath);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

        // Add the URI to the Intent.
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        // Broadcast the Intent.
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
```

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: Yes let me share you code.

Answer (score 3):

After lot of searching finally I found the solution. First we need to download video from url(if video not stored in local storage) then we apply below code.

/* Button click to share video on Instagram */

```
btn_instagram.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isPackageInstalled("com.instagram.android")) {
                    createInstagramIntent(localuri);
                }else{
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReflipActivity.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Warning");
                    alert.setMessage("Instagram App not found");
                    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    alert.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

// Check  Instagram app is installed on device or not

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

// And finally fire the Intent for Instagram

```
private void createInstagramIntent(String filename){
        String settype = "video/*";
        String mediaPath =  filename;

        // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        // Set the MIME type
        share.setType(settype);
        share.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

        // Create the URI from the media
        File media = new File(mediaPath);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

        // Add the URI to the Intent.
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        // Broadcast the Intent.
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
    }
```